# Tool to identify a missing tag for an HTML element

Tags: html, dom, process, automation

As part of the WebPage automation, I'm looking to ensure development team is adding a ID tag with unique value for each of the web element, so that, the automation team can create a easily maintainable object repository.

In this context, was looking for the help on a tool or a process that I can share with the Development team, so that, they can execute it as part of the unit testing to identify missing ID tag for each HTML element.

Any help will be highly appreciated.